# How to increase expiry date/time of Google Cloud Storage Objects in Django

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, django-rest-framework, google-cloud-storage

I have a Django REST API that uses the `storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage` as its `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE`. I noticed that media files (e.g. profile pictures of users) retrieved from any API has an `Expires` value in the URL.

Here's a sample URL to a file:
`https://storage.googleapis.com/<BUCKET_NAME>/users/a96db2f0-99a0-4691-aadb-708dc5268f77.png?Expires=1597840065&GoogleAccessId=<ACCESS_ID>&Signature=<SIGNATURE>`

If I convert that to an actual date, it's actually 24 hours from the time it was requested. How do I increase that to a very big time (e.g. 1 year)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, it's all stated in their documentation: https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/gcloud.html

> GS_EXPIRATION (optional: default is timedelta(seconds=86400))
>
> The time that a generated URL is valid before expiration. The default
> is 1 day. Public files will return a url that does not expire. Files
> will be signed by the credentials provided to django-storages (See
> GS_CREDENTIALS).
>
> Note: Default Google Compute Engine (GCE) Service accounts are unable
> to sign urls.
>
> The GS_EXPIRATION value is handled by the underlying Google library.
> It supports timedelta, datetime, or integer seconds since epoch time.

So I just do `GS_EXPIRATION = timedelta(seconds=864000)` in the settings.py so that the expiry would be 10 days.

Answer (score 0):

If the permissions for your bucket on Google Cloud Storage is set to public access (fine-grained required), you can set `GS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'publicRead'` in your `settings.py` file and the urls will be returned as public URLs which do not expire.

A sample public URL to a file would be:

`https://storage.googleapis.com/<BUCKET_NAME>/users/a96db2f0-99a0-4691-aadb-708dc5268f77.png`

Hope this helps anyone that stumbles upon this issue.